# WebRTC streaming audio and then saving offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webrtc

Is it possible to record audio from your phone's microphone, whilst streaming the audio to a PC using WebRTC, and then finally save the file locally to the PC's disk? All whilst being offline and serverless?

Comment: WebRealTimeCommunication offline and server-less ? hmm I'd say no !

Comment: You mean on a LAN without Internet access?

Comment: Yeah, like maybe some sort of ad-hoc connection over wi-fi.